# How to foreach sub(complex) associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just start to learn about PHP so I want to foreach sub associative array, but it is occurred error. I have code below:

```
$data = array(
        'WebDevelopment' => array(
            'Frontend' => array(
                'HTML' =>'Hypertext Markup Langauge' , 
                'CSS' => 'Cascading style sheet',
                'Js' => 'Java Script'
                ), 
            'Backend' => array(
                'PHP' => 'Hypertex Preprocessor',
                'Ajax'=> 'Asynchronus Js and Xml' )
            ) 
         );

     foreach ($data as $subject => $course) {
        echo "$subject";
        foreach ($WebDevelopment as $part => $value) {
            echo "$part";
            foreach ($Frontend as $Langauge => $description) {
                echo "$Langauge : $description";
            }
        }
     }
```

**Error:**

> WebDevelopment ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: WebDevelopment in
>   C:\wamp\www\mytest.php on line 21 Call Stack # Time Memory Function
>   Location 1 0.0006 134712 {main}( ) ..\mytest.php:0 ( ! ) Warning:
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\mytest.php on
>   line 21 Call Stack # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0006 134712
>   {main}( ) ..\mytest.php:0

Comment: what error? plz share the error

Comment: Please look at your variable names...

Comment: WebDevelopment
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: WebDevelopment in C:\wamp\www\mytest.php on line 21
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 134712 {main}( ) ..\mytest.php:0

( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\mytest.php on line 21
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0006 134712 {main}( ) ..\mytest.php:0

Comment: u are using undefined variables thats y u r getting undefined variables and invalid argument error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  and its working fine.

```
<?php


    $data = array(
            'WebDevelopment' => array(
                'Frontend' => array(
                    'HTML' =>'Hypertext Markup Langauge' , 
                    'CSS' => 'Cascading style sheet',
                    'Js' => 'Java Script'
                    ), 
                'Backend' => array(
                    'PHP' => 'Hypertex Preprocessor',
                    'Ajax'=> 'Asynchronus Js and Xml' )
                ) 
             );

         foreach ($data as $subject => $course) {
            echo "$subject";
            foreach ($course as $part => $value) {
                echo "$part";
                foreach ($value as $Langauge => $description) {
                    echo "$Langauge : $description";
                }
            }
         }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using undefined variables here, you can't use indexes `$Frontend` and `$WebDevelopment` as a variable here because both of them are indexes/key:

**Modified Code:**

```
foreach ($data as $subject => $course) {
    echo $subject."<br/>"; // this will print ist key
    foreach ($course as $part => $value) {
       echo $part."<br/>";  // this will print inner array'e key
       foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
           echo $key." : ".$value."<br/>";  // this will print inner last array's key and its value.
       }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
WebDevelopment
Frontend
HTML : Hypertext Markup Langauge
CSS : Cascading style sheet
Js : Java Script
Backend
PHP : Hypertex Preprocessor
Ajax : Asynchronus Js and Xml
```

Comment: @DevScripts: glad to help u